# Tangential surface of an extreme point of a convex subset of a simplex

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, linear-programming

Suppose that there is a convex set (polyhedra) $H$ which is a convex subset of a simplex $G = \{x\in R^d ~|~ \sum_{i=1}^d x_i=1, x_i \ge 0, i=1,2, ..., d \}$. Clearly, $H$ has extremal points $x^*$ (points in $H$ such that $H$ \ $x^*$ is still a convex set).

Is it possible to show that tangential surface of $x^*$, i.e., $\{ x \in R^d ~|~ \langle x, x^* \rangle = \langle x^*, x^* \rangle \}$, is a supporting hyperplane of $H$?

This problem rises from a linear programming problem. 
Suppose that we have $\bar{\mu} = \arg \max_{\mu \in H} \langle \mu, R\rangle$ for some vector $R$ and some convex polyhedra subset $H$ of a simplex. And, suppose we get $\mu^* = \arg \max_{\mu \in H} \langle \bar{\mu}, \mu \rangle$. Then, can we say that $\bar{\mu}$ and $\mu^*$ are identical?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you can from Cauchy–Schwarz inequality. Also you have to show that, you can not find any other $\mu^{*}$ in $\mathcal{H}$ in the form of $\lambda \bar{\mu}$ from the first optimal argument.